# How does C++/QML app get compiled and run on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, compilation, qml

What happens when I compile a C++/QML Application for Android?

Does all code get compiled to Java? Is the Code run as a Java application?

Or is Java only used as an entry point and running the C++/QML Code?

I found this on the docs:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-android.html#java-code

but it is not entirely clear to me.

Comment: Qt created a wrapper in Java, which gets loaded when you open the app, the rest is compiled C++ code, which is ran natively

Comment: To build an Android app, you need both the Android Software Development Kit (SDK) and Native Development Kit (NDK). Together, they will compile your C++ and QML code into the native object code for your target (typically an ARM variant). My Android apps contain no Java.